# IBM websphere to JBOSS migration

Tags: jboss, migration, websphere, ear

I want to migrate EAR and WAR applications from WAS 8 to JBOSS AS 7.

Can any one provide any Check List for the same?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139771/how-to-migrate-from-websphere-to-jboss-what-major-configurations-need-to-be-ch

Answer (score 1):

There's an automated pluggable rule-based migration tool [JBoss Windup](http://windup.jboss.org). Run the tool and get a report of what needs to be done to migrate.

You can also customize this tool to cover your specific code patterns you need to migrate. Sharing your custom rules back to the community is highly appreciated.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

WAS has tool Application Migration toolkit to check application being migrated from WebLogic /Jboss to WAS , not sure if such tool exist for JBOSS
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/compmig.htmlc